# Kafka leader vs Kafka partition leader election

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

1. Kafka cluster can have leader broker? Who elects this?
2. As far as i know, Kafka brokers rebalance partition leader when some brokers have failure. So initial partition when topic is created, leaders are elected by zookeeper or brokers?
3. When i set **1 zookeeper + 3 kafka brokers** and then **force exit broker 1**. But partition's **leader is just set NONE and didn't rebalance.** So i solved this problem by setting auto.rebalance config or adding two more zookeeper nodes(total 3). But if partition leaders are elected by brokers how 3 zookeepers solved this? Even i didn't config auto rebalance.

Answer (score 1):

All brokers are equal for replication purposes.

One broker is elected as a Controller to manage cluster operations and partition leadership for client interaction.

If broker 1 was the controller or is running Zookeeper as well, and you shutdown the whole server, then you'd should expect leader election to fail until a new controller is selected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still wondering why question 3 happened? Because if I set false auto-rebalance that should be false to rebalance partition leader. But when i added three zookeepers they rebalance partition leader. Zookeeper works for it?